Edit.blade doesn't change post status on update
/*Admin/PostController.php*/
    public function create()
    {
    return view('admin.posts.create');
    }

    public function update(PostRequest $request, Post $post)
    {
    $post->update($request->all());
    return redirect()->route('admin.posts.index', $post);
    }

/*create.blade.php*/

      <div class="container form-group">
      <div class="row border border-warning p-2 rounded-lg" style="background-color:rgba(242, 221, 146, 0.536)">
      <label for="status" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right mr-4"> Status:</label>

      <div class="form-check mt-2">
      <input class="form-radio" type="radio" name="status" id="[status,1]" value="1" checked>
      <label class="form-check-label" for="[status,1]">Hidden </label>
      </div>

      <div class="form-check mt-2">
      <input class="form-radio" type="radio" name="status" id="[status,2]" value="2">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="[status,2]">Visible</label>
      </div>

      </div></div>

/*edit.blade.php*/
      <pre><div class="container form-group row border border-warning p-2 rounded-lg">
      @if($post->status=='1')
      Status post: Hidden
      <input data-id="{{$post->status }}" class="form-radio ml-4 " type="radio" name="status" id="[status,1]" value="1" {{ $post->status }} />
      <label class="form-check-label mr-4" for="status">Visible</label>

@elseif($post->status=='2')
Status post: Visible
<input data-id="{{$post->status}}" class="form-radio ml-4" type="radio" name="status" id="[status,2]" value="2" {{ $post->status }} />
Hidden
@endif
/Creates the post but changing the editing status doesn't update the post list or publish post/

Can you please format your code as code blocks, as well as add some more detail, such as what you expected to happen but what actually happens.
